# JNI: Using CallVoidMethod() with user defined class object

Tags: java, android, c++, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I have defined a class in Java, called MyList, that I want to create and pass as an argument to a Java method from C++. I've successfully created the object and I call the callback method, but I never see the callback being called in Java.  There are no errors or exceptions:

```
jobject obj;
jclass  lClass;

// Get constructor method for MyList Class
mMyWatcher.MethodConst = mMyWatcher.mThreadEnv->GetMethodID(mMyWatcher.ClassMyList, "<init>", "()V");
if (mMyWatcher.MethodConst == NULL)
{
    LOGE("Could not find constructor method from class");
}

// Create new Java object of class MyList (call constructor basically)
obj = mMyWatcher.mThreadEnv->NewObject(mMyWatcher.ClassMyList, mMyWatcher.MethodConst);

if (mMyWatcher.MethodConst == NULL)
{
    LOGE("Could not create object from class & constructor");
}

// Get the MyList class for the new object
lClass = mMyWatcher.mThreadEnv->GetObjectClass(obj);
if (lClass == NULL)
{
    LOGE("New MyList class is NULL");
}

// Get the methods of the new class
LOGI("Getting setName()");
mMyWatcher.MethodSetName  = mMyWatcher.mThreadEnv->GetMethodID(lClass, "setName", "(Ljava/lang/String;)V");
if (mMyWatcher.MethodSetName == 0) {
    LOGE("Unable to find MyList constructor method");
}
mMyWatcher.MethodSetIndex = mMyWatcher.mThreadEnv->GetMethodID(lClass, "setIndex", "(I)V");
if (mMyWatcher.MethodSetIndex == 0) {
    LOGE("Unable to find MyList setIndex() method");
    //goto ERROR;
}
LOGI("Getting setMin()");
mMyWatcher.MethodSetMin   = mMyWatcher.mThreadEnv->GetMethodID(lClass, "setMin", "(II)V");
if (mMyWatcher.MethodSetMin == 0) {
    LOGE("Unable to find MyList constructor method");
}
LOGI("Getting setMax()");
mMyWatcher.MethodSetMax   = mMyWatcher.mThreadEnv->GetMethodID(lClass, "setMax", "(II)V");
if (mMyWatcher.MethodSetMax == 0) {
    LOGE("Unable to find MyList constructor method");
}


// Call the methods to set parameters
jstring lValue = mMyWatcher.mThreadEnv->NewStringUTF("My_PARAM_1");
mMyWatcher.mThreadEnv->CallVoidMethod(obj, mMyWatcher.MethodSetName, lValue);
mMyWatcher.mThreadEnv->DeleteLocalRef(lValue);

mMyWatcher.mThreadEnv->CallVoidMethod(obj, mMyWatcher.MethodSetIndex, 0);
mMyWatcher.mThreadEnv->CallVoidMethod(obj, mMyWatcher.MethodSetMin, 0, 0);
mMyWatcher.mThreadEnv->CallVoidMethod(obj, mMyWatcher.MethodSetMax, 0, 0);

lValue = mMyWatcher.mThreadEnv->NewStringUTF("Parm_800");
mMyWatcher.mThreadEnv->CallVoidMethod(obj, mMyWatcher.MethodAdd, 800, lValue);
mMyWatcher.mThreadEnv->DeleteLocalRef(lValue);
//This method never gets called in the java code, but there is no error
mMyWatcher.mThreadEnv->CallVoidMethod(mMyWatcher.mObject, mMyWatcher.MethodOnListUpdate2, obj);
```

I do not know why the function defined in MethodOnListUpdate2 never gets called in Java. If I change out my specific class, MyList, for a String, I get the callback in Java. I have a feeling it has to do with using a custom class but I can't pin point it. I had previously cached the mObject class and MethodOnListUpdate2 functions:

```
mMyWatcher.MethodOnListUpdate2 = pEnv->GetMethodID(mMyWatcher.ClassMyObject, "onListUpdate2", "(Lcom/example/test/MyList;)V");
if (mMyWatcher.MethodOnListUpdate2 == NULL) {
    LOGE("JNI: Error caching the methods: onListUpdate2()");
    goto ERROR;
}
```

The above code had no issues and the method was found.

Comment: Do you can post the java class code too please?

Comment: General advice: make sure you have CheckJNI enabled.  Sometimes it finds subtle problems that lead to weird behavior.  http://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-jni.html#extended_checking

Comment: Your error handling is up the spout. If you get any of those errors you cannot just continue as though you didn't. Also you are testing `mMyWatcher.MethodConst == NULL` where you should be testing `obj == null`. You should be calling one of the exception-checking methods if you get any error, to print a stack trace, so you know what exactly it is: and you should be posting that stack trace here. You can't cache `jobjects` or `jclasses` unless you use a global or weak reference.